# Changing HideFastUserSwitching value in PowerShell script using Invoke-Command on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, arguments, invoke-command

I have written a below script which prompts user to enter a remote computer name, checks "HideFastUserSwitching" value in the registry of the computer and changes it if user wishes so.
The script does its job, I have tested to change the value from 1 to 0 on one machine. But if I run the script again and try to change it back to 1, it doesn't do that. The value stays 0.
Could you please help me figure out why does this happen? If you have remarks about other pieces of code in this script, you are welcome to give me some advise, it will be appreciated.

```
$PN = (Read-Host "Enter PN#").ToUpper().Trim()
$path = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
$regKeyName = "HideFastUserSwitching"
$hideFastUserSwitchingValue = $null

Function getHideFastUserSwitchingValue {
    $regKeyValue = $null
    $parameters = @{
        ComputerName = $PN
        ScriptBlock = {
            Param ($path, $regKeyName) 
            Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $regKeyName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $regKeyName
        }
        ArgumentList = $path, $regKeyName
    }
    Invoke-Command @parameters
}

Function setHideFastUserSwitchingValue($value) {
    $parameters = @{
        ComputerName = $PN
        ScriptBlock = {
            Param ($path, $regKeyName)
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $regKeyName -Value $value
        }
        ArgumentList = $path, $regKeyName
    }
    Invoke-Command @parameters
}

$hideFastUserSwitchingValue = getHideFastUserSwitchingValue

$yesNo = (Read-Host "HideFastUserSwitching value is $hideFastUserSwitchingValue. Do you want to modify it [y/n]?").ToUpper().Trim()
if($yesNo -eq "Y") {
    $input = Read-Host "Enter the new value"
    setHideFastUserSwitchingValue($input)
    $hideFastUserSwitchingValue = getHideFastUserSwitchingValue
    Write-Host "HideFastUserSwitching value is now $hideFastUserSwitchingValue"
    } else {
        $hideFastUserSwitchingValue = getHideFastUserSwitchingValue
        Write-Host "HideFastUserSwitching value has not been modified and is equal to $hideFastUserSwitchingValue"
        }
```

Comment: don't use `$input` as it's an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) that PowerShell can take back from you at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Nothing changes after using another name for the variable unfortunately.

Comment: would suggest passing the computer name as a parameter to your function to ensure it's going to the proper computer.